# sending state with router gets undefined

Tags: angular

I have a component that uses router to navigate to another component with a boolean variable like this

```
this.router.navigate(['/consume/course/' + this.id, {state: { isFirst }} ], { replaceUrl: true });
```

in the other component I am trying to get this variable from the router like this

```
 const isFirst = this.router.getCurrentNavigation().extras.state.isFirst;
```

but I get this error:

> Cannot read property 'extras' of null

Why do I have null for the current navigation?

Also, this is my routing module for the 2nd component

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'course/:id',
    component: CourseComponent,
    canActivate: [RedirectGuard],
    data: { menuType: 'test' },
  },
];
```

Comment: I think you have the same problem with  navigate method  

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the router navigate method take two arguments the first is the commands array and the other is

```js
navigate(
     commands: any[], 
     extras: NavigationExtras = { skipLocationChange: false }): Promise<boolean>
```

so this will fixed

```js
this.router.navigate(['/consume/course/' + this.id],{ 
    state: { isFirst: 1 },
    replaceUrl: true
});
```

both previews answer are correct about getting the value but your problem was related to navigate method

Answer (score 2):

From what I know, when adding `state` to navigation, Angular is appending your values to window's `History` object. You can retrieve this value like this:

`const { isFirst } = window.history.state;`

You can read more here [Keep data in the state object during navigation in Angular](https://medium.com/javascript-everyday/keep-data-in-the-state-object-during-navigation-in-angular-5657af156fb8)

Comment: using window.history.state gives me '{navigationId: 1}'...

Answer (score 2):

from [Netanel basal:Passing Data between Routes](https://netbasal.com/set-state-object-when-navigating-in-angular-7-2-b87c5b977bb)

In a component you subscribe to activatedRoute.paramMap

```
 this.activatedRoute.paramMap
   .pipe(map(() => window.history.state))
   .subscribe(res=>{
       console.log(res)
   })
```

If you are checking in your main.app you can use router.events

```
this.router.events.pipe(
  filter(e => e instanceof NavigationStart),
  map(() => this.router.getCurrentNavigation().extras.state)
).subscribe(res=>{
       console.log(res)
})
```

And yes, always has an added variable navigationId