# Angular 9: Submit form to another component

Tags: angular

I'm making a application which is like a simplified veision of *booking.com*  where users search for available rooms at a location they want.

So I have the `SearchComponent`, which presents to the user a nice form (prompting them to enter *when* and *where* they want to travel), and once they submit the form, I want to sent these data **and redirect** to the `ResultsComponent`, which takes them and them gets from the backend all the rooms that satisfy the user's criteria, and finally presents them to the user in a nice grid system.

The only problem I have, is how to make the communication bewteen `SearchComponent` and `ResultsComponent`. In my mind it's kind of simple but for some reason I can't seem to do it. Just submit the form from `SearchComponent` to `ResultsComponent`, read the post data from `ResultsComponent` and proceed. But it seems like I don't know how to do that.

Also, when testing different stuff, I noticed that not even the simplest form works as expected in Angular. That is,

```
<form action="/results">
  <input type="text" id="location"><br>
  <input type="text" id="date"><br><br>
  <input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

does not redirect to `/results` when I click submit. And even if it worked, I'm not sure how to read the post data from the `ResultsComponent`. Note that I'm using Angular 9.

I'm stuck and I don't know how to proceed... Any help would be really appreciated!

Comment: Checkout angular navigation: https://angular.io/api/router/Router#navigate-usage-notes,  Angular is not PHP.

Comment: @DaMike, remeber that Angular is SPA, you can pass values from a component to another, see, e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63488033/sending-state-with-router-gets-undefined/63491953#63491953. Another option is store the data in a service. Remember that services are uniq along the life of an angular aplication

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it is better not to post data but rather have them in the query. For example, submitting the form would navigate to `/results?location=xyz&date=2020-09-09`. This is common way used by many websites that have search functionality and has benefit that search URL can be shared with others, or you can have direct link to search results from other websites.

In this case you can simply use `Router.navigate`. Your search component can be like:

```
export class SearchComponent {
    public searchForm = new FormGroup({
        location: new FormControl(''),
        date: new FormControl(''),
    });

    constructor(private readonly router: Router) {}

    goToResults() {
        const queryParams = this.searchForm.value;
        this. router.navigate(['/', 'results'], {
            queryParams
        });
    }
}
```

Your form can be like:

```
<form [formGroup]="searchForm">
   <input type="text" id="location" formControlName="location"><br>
   <input type="text" id="location" formControlName="date"><br>
   <button (click)="gotoResults()">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Your results component can be like:

```
export class ResultsComponent implements OnInit {
    constructor(private readonly activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute) { }
    
    ngOnInit() {
        this.activatedRoute.queryParams.subscribe((query) => {
             const location = query.location;
             const date = query.date;
             // Do whatever with location and date values here
        });
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks! It was exactly what I needed!