# How can I send an Object with router navigate in angular?

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router

I'm trying to send an object named articulo with the router navigate for use it in the other page ¿How can i do it?

`articleUpdateAction(articulo: Articulo) { this.router.navigate(['/modificarArticulos']); }`

Comment: Generally speaking, you don't send data from one route to the other with this type of pattern. Data that is shared between components is generally either placed in a service or handled with some form of state management. Unless you have a very particular setup (you give no real explanation of your situation), the very idea of passing an object to the router is not how Angular works.

Comment: @WillAlexander, why not? Even Angular Teams create (from Angular 7) the "state" to manage this kind of problems. Sure it's better pass the "id" of one article and get subscribing to activeteRouter.params like show in the [docs](https://angular.io/guide/router#accessing-query-parameters-and-fragments), but it's only if your router have params.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use the queryParams API provided by angular :

```js
articleUpdateAction(articulo: Articulo) { 
  this.router.navigate(['/modificarArticulos'], { queryParams: { articulo: articulo } 
});
```

Comment: **not** use QueryParams else [state](https://angular.io/api/router/NavigationExtras), see, e.g. this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63488033/sending-state-with-router-gets-undefined/63491953#63491953)